# SQL Server : update sequence number across multiple groups

Tags: sql-server

I would like to update a table:

```
| id | type_id | created_at | sequence |
|----|---------|------------|----------|
|  1 |       1 | 2010-04-26 | NULL     |
|  2 |       1 | 2010-04-27 | NULL     |
|  3 |       2 | 2010-04-28 | NULL     |
|  4 |       3 | 2010-04-28 | NULL     |
```

To this (note that created_at is used for ordering, and sequence is "grouped" by type_id):

```
| id | type_id | created_at | sequence |
|----|---------|------------|----------|
|  1 |       1 | 2010-04-26 |        1 |
|  2 |       1 | 2010-04-27 |        2 |
|  3 |       2 | 2010-04-28 |        1 |
|  4 |       3 | 2010-04-28 |        1 |
```

Same question has been raised but for SQL Server.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743689/is-there-a-single-query-that-can-update-a-sequence-number-across-multiple-grou)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get sequence number per `type_id` slice. Use a `CTE` to make `UPDATE` operation simpler:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
SELECT id, type_id, created_at, sequence,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type_id ORDER BY created_at) AS newSeq
FROM mytable
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET sequence = newSeq
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/330d9/1)